# Swift 3 dispatch_async or dispatch_sync (dispatch_get_main_queue()) dont work.

Tags: swift2, swift3

I have working code on Swift2.2 with dispatch_async and  dispatch_sync under below.

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){

   // Working Swift2.2

  }
```

But when i use it on Swift 3 gives me;

> 'dispatch_async' has been replaced by instance method 'DispatchQueue.asynchronously(execute:)'

That error 
I need your ideas 
Thank you !

Comment: @originaluser2 no my using code there clear

Comment: Just replace `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())` by `DispatchQueue.main.async`